# replace underscore with dash in url using notepadd++ regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

Ok i have this multiple static html and on each html urls are accompanied with underscore i want to replace all url that has underscore with dash here are the actual codes

1)

```
<a href="/category/how_to_tell_your_dad_that_you_are_pregnant/index.html">How to tell my dad that i am pregnant</a>
```

2)

```
< href="/premarital_sex/index.html">Premarital Sex</a>
```

should be

1)

```
<a href="/category/how-to-tell-your-dad-that-you-are-pregnant/index.html">How to tell my dad that i am pregnant</a>
```

2)

```
< href="/premarital-sex/index.html">Premarital Sex</a>
```

i want to replace all URL's on all of my static html how can i do that? or is it even possible?

i tried htaccess but no luck so i'll just have to use notepad++ instead or powergrep but i am not really sure how or where to start :(

thanks in advance guys

**EDIT**

I guess I'm near:

```
(href=")*[_](.+?">)
```

Comment: of all, the `url` you chose is hilariuos

Comment: Just tell him, he'll be happy for ya!

Comment: come on guys :P i seriously need help.. the REGEX come on

Comment: @markong: Help != Do-it-all-for-you. Try at least something, share the issue you have, and we'll be happy to solve that issue for you.

Comment: i just want to replace all underscores in the url to dash

Comment: i guess im near (href=")*[_](.+?">)

Comment: Yes, like:
Find What: (href="[^"]*?)_
Replace with: \1-

There's one caveat: you need to click replace several times.

Comment: @tamas rev thanks but it seems like it only finds the 1st underscore what if it has multiple underscore? thanks to yiu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily work around the problem of a missing infinite width lookbehind in Notepad++ and Sublime Text with the help of `\G` operator.

Use

```
(\bhref="|(?!^)\G)[^"<_]*\K_
```

And replace with `-`.

[image]

**Explanation:**

- `(\bhref="|(?!^)\G)` - define the leftmost boundary for a match: a whole word `href="` should be matched (`\b` is a word boundary) or match the position at the end of the previous successful match (with `(?!^)\G`)
- `[^"<_]*` - match 0+ characters other than `"`, `<` and `_`
- `\K` - omit the whole text we matched so far from the buffer
- `_` - match only this character - and only this will be replaced.

Comment: No need to click 10+ times, just click *Replace All* once.

Comment: oh my god :)) this is the solution i am looking for .. so perfect what a genius

Answer (score 1):

You need another editor that supports variable length lookbehinds. NP++ doesn't.

So, with a smart editor, sublime probably, you could do this: in one go:
Find for this: `(?<=href="[^"]*)_(?=[^"]*")` and replace them with this: `-`.

In notepad++ you can do this instead:
Find this: `(href="[^"]*)_(?=[^"]*")` and replace them with this: `\1-`. But you'll have to click Replace All several times. I.e. the url having the most underscores has 10, then you have to click it 10 times.

Comment: An infinite width lookbehind is not necessary here. There is a way to do it without that construct.

Comment: im getting invalid look behind on subime and notepad++ as well im using regex to find